# Meaning and usage of "hit the nail upon the top"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of and proper way to use the phrase *hit the nail upon the top*?

I've gotten this comment on my blog:

> Unquestionably believe that which you said. Your favorite reason appeared to be on the internet the simplest thing to be aware of. I say to you, I definitely get irked while people consider worries that they just do not know about. You managed to **hit the nail upon the top** as well as defined out the whole thing without having side effect , people can take a signal. Will likely be back to get more.

Comment: The English in that comment is a bit shaky and its vagueness prompts suspicions of spam. Google [confirms](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unquestionably+believe+that+which+you+said.+Your+favorite+reason+appeared+to+be+on+the+internet+the+simplest+thing+to+be+aware+of.%22).

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localised". OP's example is clearly bad English wriitten by a non-native speaker, and I don't see that EL&U should ordinarily be concerned with figuring such things third-hand. As it happens, in this case it's easy - but if it weren't, we couldn't ask the original writer for clarification. It's worse than being asked to interpret song lyrics, IMHO.

Comment: That looks like an incorrect translation of the idiom "hit the nail on the head" which means to get something exactly right.

Answer (score 9):

The correct phrase is "to hit the nail on the head". It means to get something exactly right, according to the person saying it. The phrase comes from carpentry - when you hit a nail with a hammer, if you don't hit it on the head you'll bend it or damage the wood (or your thumb). That makes hitting nails a metaphor for accuracy.

Example usage:

Alice: "I think that political figure X's policies are terrible."
Bob: "You really hit the nail on the head there, Alice."